# Elasticsearch multiple aggregation or terms and aggregation on a same column

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I wanted to achieve a functionality of SQL in Elasticsearch. Consider the following table:

[image]

What I wanted to achieve is aggregation on distinct value for a column, SQL equivalent:

```
select product,min(distinct price) from test group by product;
```

`Expected output:`

[image]

The aggregation could be any standard agg like `min`, `max`, `sum`, `avg`, `count` etc.

What I've already tried is using painless script, I'm able to achieve the required output through painless script but, generating painless script is quite difficult programmatically.

What I'm looking for is either an EQL query that can be generated programmatically or some java plugin that can generate a painless script programmatically.

`Edit:`

Painless script that I've tried:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "terms": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.rawMap = [:];",
        "map_script": "def product = doc['product'].value;state.rawMap.putIfAbsent(product, new ArrayList());def price = doc['price'].value;if(!state.rawMap.get(product).contains(price)){state.rawMap.get(product).add(price);}",
        "combine_script": "List outputList=new ArrayList();for (entry in state.rawMap.entrySet()) {def map=[:]; def min=entry.getValue().get(0); for(price in entry.getValue()){if(price<min){min=price;}}map.product=(entry.getKey()); map.min_price=min;outputList.add(map);}return outputList;"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the query that you've tried so far... I don't see how different from a simple terms aggregation + min sub-aggregation this could be... curious...

Comment: I've used painless script. I'm unable to achieve this using EQL.

Comment: Please show the query, otherwise we're shooting in the dark

Comment: @Val I've added the painless script that I've tried.

Answer (score 3):

No need for Painless scripting! What you want can simple by achieved by the following aggregation query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "products": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "distinct_price": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "price"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "price_stats": {
              "stats": {
                "field": "price"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, How do I find the count instead of min of the price?

Comment: You can use the `stats` aggregation and then you have everything: min, max, count, etc

Comment: The above EQL doesn't take care of finding out the distinct prices per product. It considers all the values.

Comment: It returns exactly the same results as in your second screenshot

Comment: distinct makes no sense in this context: `min(distinct price)` yields the same as `min(price)`

Comment: Distinct makes sense in `sum(distinct price)` or `avg(distinct price)` because it won't yield same result as `sum(price)` or `avg(price)`. That's the reason I've mentioned other aggs also.

Comment: I've updated the query again, please check it out

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It's not working as expected, it gives double bucketed output also it's not a correct output as it's grouped on 2 columns.

Comment: What do you mean by a) "double bucketed" and b) "grouped on 2 columns"? There are no "columns" in Elasticsearch

Comment: Terms = Group By (SQL) and field = Column (SQL).

Comment: The output is bucketed at 2 levels, the first one at the product and the second one at price. it should be only bucketed at the product.

Comment: The second level is for the "distinct" price, that's in your requirement... moreover, it's only a syntactical difference, the end result is the same, if you parse the result you get you can trivially reproduce your two columns

Answer (score 0):

Below query will give you your expected result:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "Fruites": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "min_price": {
          "min": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample Result:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 5,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "Fruites" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "apple",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "min_price" : {
            "value" : 120.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "pears",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "min_price" : {
            "value" : 150.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "banana",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "min_price" : {
            "value" : 70.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can create index mapping like below:

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "price": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "product": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample data index like below:

```
POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test","_id":"1"}}
{"product":"apple","price":"120"}
{"index":{"_index":"test","_id":"2"}}
{"product":"banana","price":"70"}
{"index":{"_index":"test","_id":"3"}}
{"product":"pears","price":"150"}
{"index":{"_index":"test","_id":"4"}}
{"product":"apple","price":"220"}
{"index":{"_index":"test","_id":"5"}}
{"product":"apple","price":"120"}
{"index":{"_index":"test","_id":"5"}}
{"product":"pears","price":"180"}
```

Comment: The above EQL doesn't take care of finding out the distinct prices per product. It considers all the values.